# How can I tell counsel's `counsel-git` to ignore certain file endings and folders

Tags: counsel

I am using [`counsel-git`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) to find and open files.

Is there any way to ignore folders and files that are ending with specific pattern.

For example: ignore folders named: `.idea` ; and files ended with `*.save` and `*.xml` or specific as `-i` or `.gitignore`. All the folders starting with `.` always show up on top; I just want to ignore some of them which I do not use.

---

config file:

```
(ivy-mode 1)
(setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t)
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c g") 'counsel-git)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counsel-git` is calling `counsel-git-cands` to build the list of files.
`counsel-git-cands` is running the shell command, which is stored in variable `counsel-git-cmd`, which has the value `"git ls-files -z --full-name --"`.

So you have two different options:

1. modify the result of function `counsel-git-cands` to remove files from the list, you do not want. i.e. add an advice, which filters the results: `(advice-add 'counsel-git-cands :filter-return #'my-filter-counsel-git-cands)`.  [Read more about advicing at the elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).
2. change the shell command line `git ls-files....` to sort out files you do not want. i.e. by using the command line option `--exclude`. You need to experiment with `git ls-files` a bit with that here. Read man page of `git-ls-files (1)`.

Comment: For example I have changed it into `git ls-files -z --full-name -- *[^.xml]` but still it returns "xml" files

Comment: Please read the manpage of `git-ls-files`! or use method 1.

Comment: `*[^.xml]` lets to exclude files that are ending with `xml` but when I make that change on the consel.el file it does not make any change in the emacs itself

Comment: I'm not familiar with git's command line, but this `--` looks supicious. Normaly this is some sort of parameter separator for command line options.

Comment: I have followed this guide : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53083343/2402577 ; for example `':!:test/*' ':!:*/test/*'` stands out to prevent folders but even it works in the terminal, within emacs it does not